# why does it give me error while importing sys module

Tags: python, syntax-error

so i am making a desktop app and i have been coming up by this error

> ```
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> >>> & C:/Users/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe c:/Users/Desktop/App/main.py
>   File "<stdin>", line 1
>     & C:/Users/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe c:/Users/Desktop/App/main.py
>     ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> >>>
> ```

this is the code

```
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets #pyqt5 module 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow #just to save some time 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon                         # ||  ||  ||  ||  ||  ||

def window(): # the main function
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) # its argument magik
    win = QMainWindow() # its like tkinter.tk() function but in pyqt
    win.setGeometry(1200, 300, 700, 700) # sets position of ui
    win.setToolTip("name asker bruh ") # sets tooltip
    win.setWindowTitle("name asker! 1.0.1") # name of ui 
    win.setWindowIcon(QIcon("Chrome.jfif")) # icon hehehe
    labl_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(win) 
    labl_name.setText("enter your first name:")
    labl_name.adjustSize()
    labl_name.move(72, 90)
    labl_mname = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    labl_mname.setText("enter your middle name:")
    labl_mname.adjustSize()
    labl_mname.move(50, 130)

    labl_lname = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    labl_lname.setText("enter your last name:")
    labl_lname.adjustSize()
    labl_lname.move(75, 170)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

i am using pyqt5 module and the sys module but theres a syntax error while importing the sys module any solutions ?
your answers will be appreciated

Comment: In which line you import the sys module?

Comment: i had imported the sys module in line 1

Comment: Im not sure, there could be 2 solutions, be sure you wrote `import sys` and why in the command line there is a `&` before the path? this could be the problem causing the syntax error

Comment: It looks like you're trying to run the file inside a python shell, not the windows command line?

Comment: @shriakhilc exactly

Comment: there is no such sumbol as ```&``` in this piece of code

Comment: `>>> & C:/Users/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe` here

Comment: @shrikhilic i use visual studio code and it acctually uses command line to execute things

Comment: try to run your code in windows cmd

Comment: and how do u run a file via cmd

Comment: I answered, look for it

Answer (score 0):

Just run the python file in a windows command line and not in a python shell :)
Write the same command in windows cmd, open it in windows apps by searching for "cmd"
and then write
`C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.9.exe C:\Users\<your-user>\Desktop\App\main.py`

Answer (score 0):

Just run this in your cmd:

`C:/Users/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe c:/Users/Desktop/App/main.py`

Comment: The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: @Badpycode you should use backslash \ instead of `/`

Comment: Search for "python.exe" or "python3.exe" in your windows search bar. Get the full path of the executable and replace it in the cmd call. Or even try to use this in your cmd: "where python" or "where python3". It will give you the executable location.